# Is there a in-place algorithm with time complexity O(n * Log(n)) to select the second largest number in an array/vector?

Tags: algorithm

It's quite clear that we see an O(n^2) algorithm to choose the second largest number, and an algorithm using tree style with O(n * Log(n)), but, with extra space cost， like below:
[image]

But, eh..., is there a in-place algorithm with time complexity O(n * Log(n)) to select the second largest number in an array/vector?

Comment: Yes, there is an O(N) algorithm actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for something very simple `O(n)`:

```
int getSecondLargest(vector<int>& vec){
    int firstLargest = INT_MIN, secondLargest = INT_MIN;
    for(auto i: vec){
        if(i >= firstLargest){
            if(firstLargest != INT_MIN){
                secondLargest = firstLargest;
            }
            firstLargest = i;
        }
        else if(i > secondLargest){
            secondLargest = i;
        }
    }
    return secondLargest;
}
```

---

`nth_element`:

Pros:

- If tomorrow you want not the second largest but say fifth largest, you won't need much code changes. The above algorithm I presented won't help.

Cons:

- If you are just looking for second largest, `nth_element` is an overkill. The swaps and/or writes are more as compared to the above algorithm I showed.

---

Why are you guys giving me `O(n)` when I am asking for `O(nlogn)`?

- You can find various in-place O(nlogn) sorting algorithms. One of them is [Block Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort).

---

No. I want it to solve it with a tree style and I want O(nlogn) and I want in place. Do you have something like that?

- No. That is not possible. When you say [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), you can't use extra space depending on `n`. Constant extra space is fine. But tree style would require `O(logn)` extra space.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact you can do this with a single pass over the range without modifying it. Here's an example algorithm:

1. Let `m` and `M` be the second largest, and largest elements. Initialize them to the smallest possible values the input range could contain.
2. For each number `n` in the range, the new second largest number depends on the relative order between `n`, `m` and `M`. The 3 possible orderings are `n < m < M`, `m < n < M`, or `m < M < n`. The new second largest element must be `m`, `n`, and `M` respectively. Essentially, `n` must be clamped between `m` and `M`.
3. The new largest number can't be `m`, so it must be the larger of `n` and `M`.

Here's a [demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/oroEbY) in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b):

```
int m = 0, M = 0;  // assuming a range with non-negative values
for (int n : v)
{
  m = std::clamp(n, m, M);
  M = std::max(n, M);
}
```

Comment: To be clear, the usual *algorithm* implementing `nth_element` is [introselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introselect), though there are [many other options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I edited the answer entirely to focus on an algorithm.